# Angular material date picker add dates automatically

Tags: angular, angular-material

Currently, I am working on angular project where i have two angular date picker and i need to update second date picker value by adding 7 days from the first date picker value

```
template file
    <form [formGroup]="form">
           
            <input
              matInput
              [matDatepicker]="picker2"
              formControlName="dateOne"
            />
            <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker2"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
            <mat-datepicker #picker2></mat-datepicker>

            <input
              matInput
              [matDatepicker]="picker3"
              formControlName="dateTwo"
              class="mainfield"
            />
            <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker3"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
</form>
ts file
  form = this.fb.group(
    {
    
     dateOne: ["", [Validators.required]],
     dateTwo: ["", [Validators.required]],
}
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using Angular Reactive forms, you can listen for changes in the `dateOne` form control value through the `valueChanges` observable and set the `dateTwo` form control value.

```ts
    this.form.get('dateOne')?.valueChanges.subscribe(date => {
      const dateTwo = new Date(new Date(date).setDate(date.getDate() + 7));
      this.form.get('dateTwo')?.setValue(dateTwo);
    });
```

**PS**: In question the form control names differ in ts and html file. The above code snippet assumes the control names are `dateOne` and `dateTwo` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Angular Reactive forms, you can listen for changes in the dateOne form control value through the valueChanges observable and set the dateTwo form control value.

```
this.form.get('dateOne')?.valueChanges.subscribe(date => {
  const dateTwo = formatDate(new Date()+ 7, 'MM/dd/yyyy', 'en');
  this.form.get('dateTwo')?.setValue(dateTwo);
});
```